# Comparing Variable Points with Highest Matching cutoff/threshold of Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

There is one variable runs in my JavaScript  example `var runs = 14;` Also I have a threshold array containing `[{"10":"lowestscore"},{"13":"lowscore"},{"20":"okscore"}]`.

I want to print message corresponding to the variable by highest matching runs Threshold with runs. Example output here should be lowscore as 14 match with 13 as highest threshold.

Kindly suggest a efficient way for computation .

I was trying with

```
$.each(runsThresholdArray, function (index, value) {
 while (value.key <  runs) {
             // some logic
              }
             })

;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
var tresholds = [{"10":"lowestscore"},{"13":"lowscore"},{"20":"okscore"}];
var runs = 14;

var result = { value: 0 }; // Result variable, the end result is stored in this.

for(var i = 0; i < tresholds.length; i++){             // Iterate over all tresholds.
  var value = parseInt(Object.keys(tresholds[i])[0]); // Get the current treshold's value.
  if(value > result.value && value <= runs){         // If the value is higher than any previous result, but not too high,
    result.value = value;                           // Remember the current result
    result.text = tresholds[i][value];
  }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result)) // `result.value` is the number, `result.text` is the text.
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, assuming array is not sorted, but the contents are well-formed and contain only the single property shown here.

```
var threshold =  [{"10":"lowestscore"},{"13":"lowscore"},{"20":"okscore"}],
    runs = 14;

var getMessage = function (threshold, runs) {
    var onlyPropertyToInt = function (obj) {
        return parseInt(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    };

    return threshold.sort(function(a,b){
            return onlyPropertyToInt(a)-onlyPropertyToInt(b)
        }).reduce(function (memo, item){
            var num = onlyPropertyToInt(item);
            if (num < runs) { memo = item[''+num] }
            return memo;
        }, null);
}

getMessage(threshold, runs);
```

Efficiency should not be an issue unless you have thousands of calls here with thousands of thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wasting a perfectly good data structure for your `threshold`: an object. A little easier to manage instead of an array of objects:

```
var threshold = {
    45: "hooray" ,
    13: "lowscore" ,
    20: "okscore" ,
    100: "god like" ,
    10: "lowestscore",
    25: "notbad",
    2: "uh oh"
}

var runs = 100;

function getThreshold(runs, threshold) {

    // get a list of your object keys, convert them to an integer
    // and then sort them
    var keys = Object.keys(threshold)
                     .map(Number)
                     .sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });

    // loop over the keys
    for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {

        // get the difference between `runs` and the current
        // element, and `runs` and the next element
        var diff = Math.abs(runs - keys[i]);
        var diffNext = Math.abs(runs - keys[i + 1]);

        // store the resulting notification from the
        // threshold object
        var tmp = threshold[keys[i]];

        // if the current difference is greater than the
        // difference of the next element, continue to the
        // next element, otherwise break out of the loop
        // and return the notification
        if (diff <= diffNext) { break; }
    }
    return tmp;
}

getThreshold(100, threshold); // god like
getThreshold(14, threshold); // lowscore
getThreshold(2, threshold); // uh oh
getThreshold(24, threshold); // notbad
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r185caj4/5/)

Comment: `if (diff <= diffNext) { break; }` ;-)

Comment: It also seems you have a leftover `out = null` in the loop, there.

Answer (score -2):

```
var runsThresholdArray = **{{**"10":"lowestscore"},{"13":"lowscore"},{"20":"okscore"**}}**;
$.each(runsThresholdArray, function **(key, value)** {
        while (**key** <  runs) {
             // some logic
        }
 });
```

**Your error : not index, value // Use : key, value**
index is for unpaired/unassociative array :
your array is rather - conceptually - an object.
**Use {} not [] (see my code).** You will have a more easy way to parse it, by the way.

JQuery doc (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) :

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( **key, value** ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```